# Softbricked, locked bootloader, no recovery

Tags: unbricking

Trying to fix a bricked Alcatel 4060A. It seems that the original root caused to to not boot, stuck at "Alcatel" logo.

I have another untouched, working copy of this phone, is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to flash a stock firmware to get everything working.
You can follow this [tutorial](http://www.alcatelroot.com/2016/03/how-to-install-easily-stock-rom-on-any-alcatel-Pixi3-Pixi3.5-Pixi4-Pixi5-Idol-dol2-Spop-Mpop-Xpop-Star-Pop.html?m=1) on how to flash a stock firmware on your phone. Download your phone's [ROM](http://www.needrom.com/category/others/a-b-c-d/brands-a/alcatel/) here.